# character to date in R using as.Date() but the answer that gives is the same date again and again

Tags: r, date, character, large-data, as.date

I'm trying to make my column named Date18 from character to date but the answer that I can get by using the function `as.Date()` is something very different. Also, I have a large sample of values.

```
str(coo)
'data.frame':   7698 obs. of  2 variables:

 $ Date18: chr  "1/3/2018 9:06" "1/3/2018 10:14" "1/3/2018 10:19" "1/3/2018 10:30" ...

 $ Amount: num  21 16.8 10.5 43.7 4.2 ...
```

`coo$Date18=as.Date(coo$Date18)`

```
str(coo)

'data.frame':   7698 obs. of  2 variables:

 $ Date18: Date, format: "0001-03-20" "0001-03-20" ...

 $ Amount: num  21 16.8 10.5 43.7 4.2 ...
```

You can see that the format of the date changed. How can I transform the date but my values will not change?

Answer (score 0):

With `as.Date`, we need to specify the `format` if it is not the default format (`"%Y-%m-%d"`)

```
as.Date(coo$Date18, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

NOTE: Here it seems that it is month then day. If it is day then month, use `as.Date(coo$Date18, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")`. Additionally, keep in mind that the `Y` has to be capitalized if the year is four numbers long e.g. 2001 and lowercase if the year is two numbers long e.g. 01.